# Does CDMA support concatenation (long) SMS

Tags: sms, smpp, cdma

1. Does CDMA support concatenated SMS?
2. If it is does which version of CDMA added support for it?
3. Which networks in the USA that use CDMA support concatenated SMS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post about this a while back:

https://www.smallbusinesstech.net/concatenated-sms/

Basically, Verizon only fully supports concatenated SMS within their own network.  When sending out from Verizon to another network concatenated SMS works correctly.  Concatenated SMS messages sent from another network to Verizon are delivered as individual SMS messages.

Sprint does not support concatenated SMS at all.

Answer (score 0):

By "long" SMS, do you mean EMS?   EMS is a series (varies by carrier), of SMS messages "stitched together".   Your phone receives N messages and presents them to you as a single object.

However, as noted, this is both device and carrier specific.   Your device is built to your carrier's specs for EMS.   THe major US carriers support EMS, but the details vary.

Comment: On GSM networks, SMS mesasges can have up to 255 parts.  [EMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Messaging_Service) looks to be a little-used messaging standard.  I suspect the OP did mean SMS.

Comment: This post is in reference to Concatenated SMS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS, which looks to be similar to EMS but is deployed widely across most cell phone networks in the United States (except, as noted, Sprint and the problems with Verizon).